# Error handling : php in template file

Tags: php, templates, frameworks, autoload

There is a strange behavior with my code and I wish understand.

In a MVC php framework i have a view object which display a template with a require

```
public function display()
{
   /* example */ 
   require_once $this->viewPath;
}
```

It works but I have a problem with error handling, if I do something wrong which normally throw an new Exception, it don't work everytime.

**Case 1 :** In this case, everything is fine an exception is thrown by my autoload cause it can't find the Class

```
/* example.phtml or .html or .tpl */
<?php WrongClassName::get("example"); ?>
```

**Case 2 :** FAIL ! The same call is done, but this time wrap by double quotes : There is no error displayed, no exception, no call to autoload function, but it's like a die, nothing is executed after that

```
/* example.phtml or .html or .tpl */
<div data-attribute="<?php WrongClassName::get('example'); ?>">Hello</div>
```

**Case 3 :** SUCCESS ! Same but with simple quote, error handling works fine like in **case 1**, an exception is thrown by my autoload function

```
/* example.phtml or .html or .tpl */
<div data-attribute='<?php WrongClassName::get("example"); ?>'>Hello</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your response

Comment: ... what ide are you coding in? any basic one (i.e. netbeans) would show you the html syntax error of using the double-quotes. in your first exemple the second double-quotes ends the `data-attribute` element too soon.

Comment: Hello, thank for your answer. In case 2; if example is wrapped by simple quote (i edited the main message) I have the same issue, but may be i didn't understand your message,

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that it must have something to do with your template parser. The parser recognizes the PHP tag and encloses it properly when it is within a single quote, but the double quote makes it die rather than throw the error.

I expect that wrapping the whole thing in PHP would work regardless of quote type. In other words both of the following would work like your Cases 1 and 3:

```
<?php echo '<div data-attribute="' . WrongClassName::get("example") . '">Hello</div>'; ?>

<?php echo "<div data-attribute='" . WrongClassName::get("example") . "'>Hello</div>"; ?>
```